# MySQL evaluate case with subquery

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a custom sort that involves the count of some records in another table. For example, if one record has no records associated with it in the other table, it should appear higher in the sort than if it had one or more records. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT People.*, Organizations.Name AS Organization_Name,
   (CASE
        WHEN Sent IS NULL AND COUNT(SELECT * FROM Graphics WHERE People.Organization_ID = Graphics.Organization_ID) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END) AS Status
FROM People
LEFT JOIN Organizations ON Organizations.ID = People.Organization_ID
ORDER BY Status ASC
```

The subquery within the `COUNT` is not working. What is the correct way to do something like this?

**Update:** I moved the case statement into the `order by` clause and added a `join`:

```
SELECT People.*, Organizations.Name AS Organization_Name
FROM People
LEFT JOIN Organizations ON Organizations.ID = People.Organization_ID
LEFT JOIN Graphics ON Graphics.Organization_ID = People.Organization_ID
GROUP BY People.ID
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN Sent IS NULL AND Graphics.ID IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END ASC
```

So if if the `People` record does not have any graphics, `Graphics.ID` will be null. This achieves the immediate need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you tried does not work, it can be done by joining against a subquery, and placing the `CASE` expression into `ORDER BY` as well:

```
SELECT 
  People.*,
  orgcount.num
FROM People JOIN (
  SELECT Organization_ID, COUNT(*) AS num FROM Graphics GROUP BY Organization_ID
) orgcount ON People.Organization_ID = orgcount.num
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN Sent IS NULL AND orgcount.num = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
   orgcount.num DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an outer join to the Graphics table to get the data needed for your sort.

Since I don't know your schema, I made an assumption that the People table has a primary key column called ID. If the PK column has a different name, you should substitute that in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT People.*, (count(Distinct Graphics.Organization_ID) > 0) as Status
FROM People
LEFT OUTER JOIN Graphics ON People.Organization_ID = Graphics.Organization_ID
GROUP BY People.ID
ORDER BY Status ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly straight forward with a LEFT JOIN provided you have some kind of primary key in the People table to GROUP on;

```
SELECT p.*, sent IS NOT NULL or COUNT(g.Organization_ID) Status
FROM People p LEFT JOIN Graphics g ON g.Organization_ID = p.Organization_ID
GROUP BY p.primary_key
ORDER BY Status
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f4fe/1).